# strncmp not matching correctly

Tags: c++, c, strncmp

I have no idea how to work with strings in C:

here's a part of my server:
The break never gets called, even though I supply the character '/' through telnet.

Ideally, this would buffer up the string called get by adding the string ch to it over and over again until it reaches a certain character, or, better yet, a string (but write now it is supposed to work with a character but i'd love to know how to do it with a string so I can design a protocol that uses CR+LF as the seperator).

```
   char ch;
    int index = 0;
    char get[1024];
    const char str[] = "/";

    if ( read( client, &ch, 1 ) < 0 )
    {
        perror( "read" );

        get[index] = ch;
        index++;

        int compareResult = strncmp(str, &ch, 5);

        if(compareResult == 0){
            index = 0;
            close( client );
            printf( "server responded, connection closed" );
            break;
        }
    }

    //if ( write( client, &ch, 1 ) < 0 ) { perror( "write" ); break; }

    printf( "got stuff" );
```

why does it not reach the

```
printf( "server responded, connection closed" );
```

line?

full code for server: http://pastebin.com/j5tX3TEx

Comment: Why do you compare two single characters as strings and why do you have 5 to strncmp when `str` is just one character long and `&ch` can only be one character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
int compareResult = strncmp(str, &ch, 5);
```

invokes undefined behavior. You're passing `&ch`, the address of a single `char` to a function expecting a *string* pointer. So, it will look at at most 5 characters starting from the address of `&ch`, which of course is only *one* character of data.

Your entire read logic is very strange, it should do larger reads and not one character at a time.

Comment: first c program! can you write some example code to define best practices?

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
int compareResult = strncmp(str, &ch, 5);
```

is not correct

ch is one character but you compare 5 characters. the second argument must be a string and not a char.

if it is a typo and you meant `get` then you need to \0 terminate the string after you received the last
character in order to use `get` as argument. alternatively use `memcmp` to compare bytes regardless whether
they are strings or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see. Seems like you are comparing an array of char (str) to a char (ch)

```
if(ch == '/'){
    index = 0;
    close( client );
    printf( "server responded, connection closed" );
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this instead:

```
if(ch == '/'){
      index = 0;
      close( client );
      printf( "server responded, connection closed" );
      break;
}
```

This is also faster than using a function(such as `strncmp`)

Answer (score 0):

```
read( client, &ch, 1 ) < 0
```

why `< 0`? Everything seems to be done there in your code while read returns the number of bytes read.